# gz_ros2_control and gazebo not working

Tags: gazebo, ros2-control

I can't get any gz_ros2_control_demo example to work either on Rolling + Harmonic or Rolling + Garden

**Configuration :**
Docker Ubuntu 22.04 on Ubuntu 22.04
ROS Rolling + Garden or ROS Rolling + Harmonic
ros_gz (ros2), gz_ros2_control(main) built from source

**Step to reproduce :**
Command "ros2 launch gz_ros2_control_demos diff_drive_example.launch.py" (or any other example)

```
Error

[ruby $(which gz) sim-2] [Err] [UserCommands.cc:1097] Error Code 30: Msg: Error parsing XML from string: 
Error=XML_ERROR_PARSING_DECLARATION ErrorID=11 (0xb) Line number=1
 [ruby $(which gz) sim-2] [Err] [UserCommands.cc:1097] Error Code 30:

Msg: Unable to read SDF string: <?xml v
```

Should I switch and use other branches ? Am I doing something wrong ?
I also tried to use the docker file provided in the Docker folder, but i seems to be using Humble with fortress, which means it's using the old naming convention (ign). Also, I can't try Humble because gz_ros2_control only compiles on humble branch which use the ign naming convention.

**Could any one share a working docker with working gz_ros2_control_demo examples using the new gz_sim ?**

Comment: Well, it seems to have been solved since commit [#210](https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/pull/210) on the gz_ros2_control.

If anyone interested, I've created a [docker-compose](https://gitlab.com/kytheralab/applications/docker_ros) file that creates a container with ROS2 Rolling and Gazebo Garden